# How would I use sed to add the sudo group to sudoers?

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I would like to use `sed` to automatically uncomment the `sudo` group in `/etc/sudoers`. Thing is, I don't know how to do this, nor do I think I could figure it out myself.

I only have one shot to do this correctly, since this is being used in a script for my friend. The `sudo` group is uncommented in `/etc/sudoers`, and I am looking for a `sed` command that can uncomment it for my by adding it to a script.

Could someone help?

Comment: Don't do this. Most Linux distros enable included files in `/etc/sudoers.d`, so drop a file there with the exact contents you want after checking with `visudo`.

Comment: @muru so I can just put `sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL` in a directory in `etc/sudoers.d`? Is there a specific name I need to give it? Could you direct me to some documentation for it?

Comment: Yes. See [`man 5 sudoers`, "Including other files from within sudoers"](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.5/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers): "sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’ character to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files. Files are parsed in sorted lexical order. That is, /etc/sudoers.d/01_first will be parsed before /etc/sudoers.d/10_second. ..." (`%sudo` for a group, though, IIRC)

Comment: Add them to the appropriate _group_ instead, and make sure that the group has the correct settings in `sudoers`. If it needs to be scripted, it's easier to modify users' secondary groups.